# Passing a function through an SQL Statement

Tags: sql, vba, function, ms-access

I am relatively new to Access and I hope you can help with a question.

```
Private_Sub Form_Load()

Dim db as DAO.Database
Dim rs as DAO.Recordset
Dim StrSQL as String

Set db = CurrentDb

StrSQL = "Select GetDateDiff(Date1, Date2) as DateDifference from tblDattes"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(StrSQL)

.....

End Sub
```

The GetDateDiff is a Function that takes two paramaters as Variants. I am unsure how the Function gets used within the SQL code.

Answer (score 0):

assuming Date1 and Date2 are fields of the table tblDattes.

```
StrSQL = "Select GetDateDiff(Date1, Date2) as DateDifference from tblDattes" 
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(StrSQL)
```

Will work.
But you should question yourself why you are using Variant parameters in your GetDateDiff function. In general avoid Variant and opt for Date fields. Your function will have to perform a check in case one of the parameters (or both) are Null.

P.S. Also make sure the name of your table is really tblDattes (with two 't')